# How do you filter a collection of data that has an assigned date, by the date you want?

Tags: r, date, select

An untidy dataframe is given
The values are given through various dates, I want to seek all values from a specific financial year for consistency.

I have tried arrange() and group by() but I cannot decide if I should group the dates I need into a vector first or just use the column values.

Comment: Please share a small example of your input and your desired output. As-is, your question is very unclear. Perhaps read the Help Center's article on [How to make a minimal, reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or the R-specific FAQ on [How to make a reproducible example in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: The friendliest way to share data is with `dput()`, which makes a copy/pasteable version of your data including all data structure information. Use `dput(your_data[1:5, 2:4])` to share the first 5 rows of columns 2 through 4. Pick a small subset of data to share that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Some relevant questions that will be easily answered if you share an example like this: what does your data look like? Are the dates in a single column, or spread over multiple column or even column names? How is the data "untidy"? Are the dates in a useful `Date` class, or are they `character`s or something else? What do you want the result to be? etc.